# Docker - Environment variables not overwriting php.ini

Tags: php, docker, environment-variables

I'm having a custom php app running on docker. I have set up some env variables for configuring the php.ini or the apache but when I do `docker-compose up --build` and try to access the app (index.php) from the browser I can see the env variables have not overwritting the php.ini file or the apache conf. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

These are my files

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    app:
        container_name: myapp
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        networks:
            - appnet
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch
COPY docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY docker/config/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY docker/config/php/conf.d/*.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
COPY . /var/www/html/
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
```

php.ini

```
date.timezone = ${PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE}
display_errors = ${PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS}
error_reporting = ${PHP_ERROR_REPORTING}
```

.env

```
PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE = Europe/London
PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS = 1
PHP_ERROR_REPORTING = -1
```

index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have spaces in your `.env` file.

Try changing it to:

```
PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=Europe/London
PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=1
PHP_ERROR_REPORTING=-1
```

> Compose expects each line in an env file to be in VAR=VAL format.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/